# How to handle 4xx and 5xx errors in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, httpd.conf

Can anyone please let me know how to handle 4xx and 5xx errors in CodeIgniter? I have to show different templates to user for each case. Currently I am able to handle only 404 error with show_404() function. Please let me know how to find and handle other errors such as following:

400     Bad Request
401     Authorization Required
402     Payment Required (not used yet)
403     Forbidden
405     Method Not Allowed
406     Not Acceptable (encoding)
407     Proxy Authentication Required
408     Request Timed Out
409     Conflicting Request
410     Gone
411     Content Length Required
412     Precondition Failed
413     Request Entity Too Long
414     Request URI Too Long
415     Unsupported Media Type

Server Errors

500     Internal Server Error
501     Not Implemented
502     Bad Gateway
503     Service Unavailable
504     Gateway Timeout
505     HTTP Version Not Supported

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add .htaccess rules to tell the web server to send the errors to your system.

An example would be:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error/e400
ErrorDocument 403 /error/e403
```

And then have CodeIgnitor handle the rest.

Comment: I have added following lines in my httpd.conf file: 

    `ErrorDocument 403 /forbid.html
     ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
     ErrorDocument 500 /somepage.html`

Among these directives only     `ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html` is working. Can you please let me know how to get work with other than 404 code? Actually I have to execute some php code when particular error occurs. Please suggest.